# Как определить, почему скрипт на стороне сервера выдает ошибку?

Tags: python, requests

Результатом выполнения кода, представленного ниже, является вывод статуса 404. Мне подсказали, что, видимо, скрипт на стороне сервера, глядя на данные, которые я ему отправил, решил мой запрос не выполнять и вернуть 404. То есть мне надо разобраться, какие данные для нормальной работы принимает этот скрипт. Как эти сделать? Есть ли какой то алгоритм по выяснению методов работы с конкретным веб приложением?

Вот код

```
import requests


def vote_mcsl(nickname: str):
    request_url = r'https://minecraft-server-list.com/servers/voter10.php'
    data = {'ipennn': '2001%3A67c%3A2660%3A425%3Ae%3A%3A68',
            'iden': '399188',
            'ignn': nickname,
            'g-recaptcha-response': '03AGdBq24V07XQVFqJtOQ1tZodGoiWhUgLu3pnrlFw4ECVu8hugpP_M7m4afGDg2knJNPt3D03p2RpbXO55kd0v94Zj8t8fMTmvutuwVckMe8KTrMeWY-sOFZDtaFeyc6afYP5f1OUh1y8c78s6AutGoiMdiZIF5lmPaSRgdaZdnEDmbLez-9XNU1sstNP3imyTqp8wUQDSladtLmav4JqfJo1eV8UQ2gCipfYKyn3yOsurBplTSVN2pInUBOQm8Jy_AxdRNtMRStOX_NAoTm04so-yz0M0yg55deb39vuunJJ5tPXirHSXnppiAF8efwltmYSFi7lkmPSG8G9v-v_ZHahatxJn3xzuOLhWMjYgomDSuRSxFXySoKBRyJWKMdZ9vYp06-dY4xjjd3pikqjvJTCrf8aju3Y4a31XQYebHjE3EeqEoUBmmRt9e-ZbUqddSWK-58M3K7h__j6DOfKh2-YoSQikL3uDw'}
    resp = requests.post(request_url, data=data)
    print(resp.status_code)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    vote_mcsl('dave')
```

Comment: UserAgent попробуйте отправить

Comment: Тоже не помогло

Comment: 404 - означает, что нет такого endpoint-a. Т.е. переданный адрес серверу неизвестен, он не обрабатывает запросы по пути "/servers/voter10.php". Нет такого скрипта, или нужно авторизоваться. Общего алгоритма нет, возможно автор ресурса может предоставить документацию, как обращаться к API сервера.

Comment: В панеле разработчика в браузере, когда я нажимаю на кнопку голосования отправляется запрос по вот этой ссылке https://minecraft-server-list.com/servers/voter10.php?voteses=34929805 . И статус код у него 200. Так как тогда нет этого скрипта? Не понимаю

Comment: @RomanKonoval (упоминание, чтобы привлечь ваше внимание)

Comment: Значит нужно авторизоваться. Если пользователь неавторизован - тут сервер возвращает 404. Смотрите в инструментах разработчика все заголовки, что посылает браузер и посылайте такие же.

Comment: @RomanKonoval ради интереса я попробовал скопировать всё из запроса браузера к серверу (И заголовки, и данные, и параметры), но сервер всё равно вернул 404

Comment: Для пост запроса вполне возможно, что сервер требует уникальный идентификатор, который клинет получает перед тем как делать пост, с помощью get. Попробуйте повторить пост из браузера и посмотрите, меняется ли какой-то из параметров. В общем вам нужно повторить то, что делает браузер, а это может означать, что нужно сначала сделать гет, чтоб получить какие-то из параметров, которые нужны для пост.